# Not Riemann integrable function which can be Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration

Consider the function $f: [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} \frac{m}{n} &\text{ if }  x \in \mathbb{Q}, x = \frac{m}{n}, (m,n) = 1 \\
0 &\text{ if } x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}
$$
where $(m,n)$ is the greatest common divisor of $m,n$.
This function is NOT Riemann Integrable on $[0,1]$ but I have a problem with the special case where $m = 0$. The author of the question failed to specify that $m \neq 0$, though we have $\gcd(n,m) = 1$.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about number of partitions. I think what the author wants to say is that $f(x)=1/x$ if $x\in{\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: The only definition we have of $n$, is this: $P_n$ is defined as the partition of $[a,b]$ with $n$ subintervals of equal length. And when $x$ is rational, then indeed $f(x) = m/n$.

Comment: The number of partitions in an integral bound is not at all related to the denominator of $x$. So be sure not to call them both $n$.

Comment: The definition does fail to give a value for $f(0)$. But if it we specify any real value for $f(0)$, the value of one point can't change whether the function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @aschepler. I can easily prove it is not Riemann integrable. The problem for me is with the integer $m$. If $m = 0$ AND $n = 1$ (which is an option given how the question is asked), then $f(x) = 0$ everywhere on $[0,1]$. I guess I just need to mention this fact.

Comment: BTW, this is a new class, so I don't know if the teacher is using chicanery here or if he was simply too lazy here and I hate to start questioning his writing on the first week of class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no rational number $x$ for which $x = n/0$ for some $n$, i.e. $m$ can never be zero.

You also seem to be assuming that values of $m$ and $n$ determine the value of $f$ on the entire interval. This is not true - differing values of $x$ will have differing values of $m$ and $n$, and those $m$ and $n$ values only determine the value of $f$ at that one, single value of $x$.

As to what you say about partitions, I don't really understand it, but again it sounds like you think you can make different choices of $m$ and $n$, and this will lead to different "versions" of the function $f$. This is not the case - $f$ is uniquely defined by what is written.

Comment: typo fixed.. $x = m/n$

Comment: Okay, so when $x =0$,  $m = 0$ and $n =1$, so $f(0) =0/1=0$.

Comment: Thanks man. this was my error: "You also seem to be assuming that values of 
m and  determine the value of  on the entire interval". I got it now.

Comment: The question was so terse. No definitions for n or m, etc... Probably he took it from Rudin.

Comment: Glad to help. Our minds can easily get fixated on a particular interpretation, and we don't even notice it!

Comment: Yeah, math is often written very tersely and compactly. I've sometimes spent 10 minutes trying to understand 2 lines of text in a math article. You'll get better at understanding it with practice.